# Is adding another programming language an appropriate edit of a post?

Tags: discussion, edits

To be honest, I'm not especially bothered by [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4315290/revisions), as it does not necessarily detract from my answer. In fact, for some, it probably adds value. Admittedly, I'm not so certain, since the edit adds merely a translation from one CLR language to another.

I can't help but feel like the answer is not "mine", in the sense that it has not only been proofread or adjusted for presentation, but materially enhanced. The C# edits, I would think, would be better posted as a separate answer so that the editor could receive deserved community support and upvotes.

So, to the point of my question: is inserting an alternative programming-language-translated version of a response an appropriate edit on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It's appropriate if it doesn't bother you and it is correct. Which I assume from this post that the first is not true but the second is since you said "it probably adds value". But, ultimately, it's up to you. You can rollback if you want and suggest in a comment he post another answer (could cause conflict). Or let it be. The editor probably thought your answer was good enough that him leaving another answer just to add an extra bit wasn't worth it and that you deserved the credit.

Comment: dat bold and italics :(

Comment: The Bold + Italics alone makes me reach for the rollback button. While I understand the reason for emphasis on **UserGroup** vs. **People**, the rest *does* not really `make` **sense** to me.

Comment: Looking at the edit history you linked, it looks like the answer is "no" since it got removed by a mod.

Comment: Personally, I don't like additional code in most instances. I think it would be more acceptable if the question had a C# tag and you failed to address it. But as it's written, it would be an accident for anyone using C# to find it without the tag. I understand the relationship, but the two are not completely dependent on each other, and in fact, at least in my experience, not *all* SharePoint solutions support independently coded C#, i.e.; SharePoint 365.

Comment: @Jongware: I still refuse to believe it's not a cultural thing (obviously not saying that makes it OK, but it does make me feel like I'm being prejudiced or whatever). I wonder what can be done about it.

Answer (score 50):

In the general case, I believe one should not add code to an existing answer, unless it is a trivial fix that does not change the meaning of the original code (e.g. an obvious typo).

For more elaborate fixes, it is better to call the answerer out on it in a comment and suggest the change, or to post your own fixed answer that references the incorrect one.

Now, in your specific case, the editor has added an alternate way of invoking a SharePoint web service. Web services are meant to be language-agnostic as far as the caller is concerned, which means we could add a whole bunch of code snippets to your answer, each one tied to our language of choice: you initially used PowerShell, the editor added C#, we could add Javascript or Python or C or Lisp or... you get my drift.

Since obviously allowing this behavior for *n* languages is not a good idea, I think allowing it for two languages is not a good idea either. To me, that edit should be rolled back.

Comment: I agree here, +1 My personal policy is to point out code issues in the comments rather than do a direct edit. I only directly edit code for "whitespace issues" (too many extra line breaks, for example), which usually result from copy-paste.

Comment: I agree *in this particular case* that the edit was probably inappropriate. But, ugh. I hate to see all the comments from people who are gun-shy about making substantial edits to answers. If you want to add sample code to one of my answers where I haven't included it, *please do so*. If I blundered when typing one of the code snippets I did include, *please fix the mistake*. There is just no reason to leave noisy comments asking people to fix stuff that you could just as easily fix yourself. Remember the goal here: canonical, high-quality answers to programming questions.

Comment: I agree that having *n* languages on a single answer is not good, I have frequently looked at a question where the accepted answer was in a different language than the one I was using, but there was another answer that *was* in my current language.  Providing code in an additional language is helpful, but should be its own answer (referencing the original).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Frédéric Hamidi's recommendation that the edit be rolled back (which I support), I think the edit you posted constitutes a complete violation of the edit guideline that says to "always respect the original author".

From the question EDIT page (difficult to link to as it relies on an answer or question still existing BUT, [here is a link to the edit page of THIS question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/260739/edit)):

[image]

I would dare to wonder if the editor in question had forgotten that they were in "editing" mode an and not "answer" mode, if not for the edit summary which suggests that the editor knew exactly where they were…

Comment: Where is this edit guideline that you mention documented? I tried to link to it, but couldn't find it in [the Help Center's page on editing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Comment: @CodyGray The guideline is displayed on the edit page whenever you edit an answer. I will seek to revert this answer to its original format and include a picture of the edit screen.

Answer (score 3):

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235299/how-to-remove-duplicate-entries-that-both-lists-have-in-common), someone answered in C#, so in my original post I appended the solution in VB.NET under a heading of "UPDATE".

Having someone other than the original poster (poster, answerer, commenter, ...) edit their posts is asking the OP to take responsibility for the content as someone else has edited it. That might work for Wikipedia, where this is expected, but with SE using 'gamification', moderators can take away 'points' of mine for content I had nothing to do with, if you think about it.

I guess what I'm trying to add to the discussion is that it isn't that the other versions weren't valuable. What does matter is editing someone else's content to make it look like your edits are what they are responsible for saying. I can't see a good outcome for that... It's just as easy to write your own, I would hope/think.

I thanked the answerer, of course, but left their answer alone, giving them credit (and a link to their profile) in the update.

That seemed like the most polite way.

The last part of my opinion/answer, "*Is there a better way?*" was removed as per a suggestion by Frédéric Hamidi.

pat
:)

Comment: This is your own question in itself, so you should not post it as an answer to this one. Instead, search for possible duplicates, and if you really don't find any, post your own question. *Meta short answer: On SO, do post your own answer instead of updating your original question.*

Comment: Thanks, but I gently disagree. In my case, I was asking whether the answer (which are really opinions, if you get down to it) was what they were looking for, and inviting additional commentary from others. This is just being polite.

Comment: I think your point about the burden of responsibility for someone else's answer is poignant. It particularly concerns low rep users like yourself and me, to whom rep point are extraordinarily precious.